# Environment variable in shell

Tags: shell

I would like to run a sh file in Linux or Windows to activate and lunch a python script. I found that %os% is the variable which tell the distribution in Windows, so I tryed this code :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "start"

if [ %OS% == "Windows_NT" ]; then
  echo "In windows env"
  cd venv/Scripts || exit
  activate.bat
  python script.py
else
  source venv/bin/activate
  python python.py
fi
```

The problem is that it never goes on the if Windows (I run it with Windows 10)

Could you help me pls ?

Comment: `%os%` is a Powershell(?) variable, not a `bash` variable.

Comment: What do you get as an output for `echo %OS%`? That should tell you if a) it's the wrong env variable or b) you check against the wrong value or c) if not a or b then something with your script is wrong

Comment: @Tschösi You would get `%OS%`, because its an ordinary string as far as `bash` is concerned.

Comment: @Tschösi I got "Windows_NT" when I type it in a cmd, but in the .sh it's not working idk why

Comment: @chepner what should I used ?

Comment: Possibly `[ "$OSTYPE" = ... ]`, though I don't know what exact value that variable will have on Windows 10.

Comment: @natdop : `%OS%` does not make sense. It is just the literal string `%,O,S,%`. Variables (including environment variables) are expanded by prefixing them with a `$`, i.e. `$OS. If you want to catch the case that the variable is unset or empty, expand it as i.e. `${OS?:empty}`.

Comment: @natdop : I suggest to read [this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) document, which explains everything you need for your case.